# what's the correct way to write a regular expression that validate hundredths?

Tags: regex

I’m trying to write a regular expression that validate minutes, seconds and hundredths. I found this description that a regular expression can be written like this `hhmmsscc [00-24][00-59] [00-59][00-99]` where `cc` is a hundredth of a second `[00-99]`. The regex that I want to write doesn’t need to have hours.  As an intent to write a regex that doesn’t contain hours,  I wrote `/^([00-59]):([0-59]):([00-99])$/` but that doesn’t work.

Does anybody can look at that regex and tell me what’s the correct way to write a regex that validate only `mmsscc`?

Comment: The source where you found your example is horribly wrong. Each single character inside square brackets is only used *once*, and the dash `-` indicates a *range* - but still for a single character only. So `[00-24]` will match *one* character, out of the set `0`, `0` to `2`, and `4` - one of `0124`.

Comment: You'd be much better off parsing it as an integer and doing number comparisons. Or, depending on the language you're using, use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: Are you using any specific programming language?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
 |     hours       |   min   |   sec   | hundreds |
```

Comment: Don't hhmm go from 00.00 - 23.59 ?

Comment: My bad ) There's really only 23 hours in a day. Fixed.

Comment: I mean 0-23 )) ... Here's a late evening

Comment: Correct ... but the OP doesn't need the hours part.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
(?:1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:[0-5][0-9]){2}[0-9]{2}

(?:1[0-9]|2[0-3]) -> hh
(?:[0-5][0-9]){2} -> mmss
[0-9]{2} -> cc
```

Your solution doesn't work because Regular Expression are used for lexical match, so you need to test each character separately

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jE1nE1/3)